# SQL Server 2008: Looping through results of SELECT + performing other queries depending on position in loop and result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a table that holds the location and timestamp information from a GPS module. The table looks something like this:

```
declare @VehicleData table
(
    [TimeStamp] DateTime,
    Latitude float,
    Longitude float
)

insert into @VehicleData
values  ('2012/03/06 10:00', 1, 1),
        ('2012/03/06 10:01', 1, 2),
        ('2012/03/06 11:00', 0, 0),
        ('2012/03/06 11:01', 0, 0),
        ('2012/03/06 11:02', 2, 2),
        ('2012/03/06 11:03', 2, 2),
        ('2012/03/06 11:04', 2, 3),
        ('2012/03/06 11:20', 0, 0),
        ('2012/03/06 11:21', 5, 5),
        ('2012/03/06 11:22', 5, 6),
        ('2012/03/06 11:23', 5, 6),
        ('2012/03/06 11:24', 5, 7),
        ('2012/03/06 11:25', 5, 8)
```

You'll notice that some of the data points have latitude and longitude values of 0, due to the GPS module not have a fix at the time. What I'd like to do when retrieving data points from this table is to set all zero latitude and longitude values to the last non-zero latitude and longitude values. I currently do this in my client side code, but I'd like to integrate this into my database stored procedures. The client side code looks something like this:

```
Dim StartDate = '2012/03/06 11:00'
Dim EndDate = '2012/03/06 11:25'

Dim Results = GetVehicleDataBetweenDates(StartDate, EndDate)

Dim LastKnownLatitude = 0, LastKnownLongitude = 0

If Results(0).Latitude = 0 Then
    'Query database for last non-zero position before StartDate
    GetLastKnownPositionBeforeDate(StartDate, LastKnownLatitude , LastKnownLongitude )
Else
    LastKnownLatitude = Results(0).Latitude
    LastKnownLongitude = Results(0).Longitude
EndIf

For i = 0 to Results.Count - 1
    If Results(i).Latitude = 0 Then
        Results(i).Latitude = LastKnownLatitude
        Results(i).Longitude = LastKnownLongitude
    Else
        LastKnownLatitude = Results(i).Latitude
        LastKnownLongitude = Results(i).Longitude
    EndIf
Next
```

The above could should result in the following results, with the arrows pointing to the previously zero locations:

```
('2012/03/06 11:00', 1, 2), <-- 
('2012/03/06 11:01', 1, 2), <--
('2012/03/06 11:02', 2, 2),
('2012/03/06 11:03', 2, 2),
('2012/03/06 11:04', 2, 3),
('2012/03/06 11:20', 2, 3), <--
('2012/03/06 11:21', 5, 5),
('2012/03/06 11:22', 5, 6),
('2012/03/06 11:23', 5, 6),
('2012/03/06 11:24', 5, 7),
('2012/03/06 11:25', 5, 8)
```

How would I go about implementing this same functionality in SQL?

**Addendum:** Thanks for all the responses so far. I ought to point out that I am not interested in updating the original table - I would only like to modify the results of the query. The reason for this is because the rows in the table are not added in chronological order.

Comment: With regards to your Addendum, danihp's answer is exactly what you require.

Comment: Why don't you just ignore them? ie select * from @VehicleData where lattitude <> 0 and longitude <> 0

Comment: @Adrian: In order to simplify my question, I didn't include the full table description. As well as the time and location, each row also has some data related to the status of the module at the time. I need that information, even if there is no valid location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subquery table to get last knowed position:

```
select 
 [timestamp],
 case 
   when latitude>0 then latitude
   else (select top 1 latitude 
         from @VehicleData v2
         where 
           latitude > 0 and
           v2.[TimeStamp] < v1.[TimeStamp]
         order by v2.[TimeStamp] desc )
   end
   as latitude
from 
 @VehicleData v1
```

The sample is for latitude, do the same subquery to get longitude.

Comment: This does exactly what I need, thanks. I have a question regarding performance: in my sample client side code, I only query the database for the last non-zero location at the beginning. Afterwards, I store a local copy of the location and use it when needed. In your query, every time the latitude or longitude is zero, a select statement is executed. I'm curious as to how this will impact performance.

Comment: To improve performance remember to create index over TimeStamp column.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little messy, but adding these two commands into your SQL will do as you need:

```
UPDATE V
SET Latitude = (SELECT Latitude FROM @VehicleData WHERE [TimeStamp] = (SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) FROM @VehicleData WHERE [TimeStamp] < V.[TimeStamp] AND [Latitude] <> 0))
FROM @VehicleData V
WHERE Latitude = 0

UPDATE V
SET Longitude = (SELECT Longitude FROM @VehicleData WHERE [TimeStamp] = (SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) FROM @VehicleData WHERE [TimeStamp] < V.[TimeStamp] AND [Longitude] <> 0))
FROM @VehicleData V
WHERE Longitude = 0
```

Hope this helps.

Here is my result set:

```
2012-03-06 10:00 | 1 | 1
2012-03-06 10:01 | 1 | 2
2012-03-06 11:00 | 1 | 2
2012-03-06 11:01 | 1 | 2
2012-03-06 11:02 | 2 | 2
2012-03-06 11:03 | 2 | 2
2012-03-06 11:04 | 2 | 3
2012-03-06 11:20 | 2 | 3
2012-03-06 11:21 | 5 | 5
2012-03-06 11:22 | 5 | 6
2012-03-06 11:23 | 5 | 6
2012-03-06 11:24 | 5 | 7
2012-03-06 11:25 | 5 | 8
```

Comment: You could merge these two UPDATEs into a single UPDATE doing something like: `SET Latitude = (...), Longitude = (...) FROM [...] WHERE Latitude = 0 AND Longitude = 0`. This would also protect againt any entries where Latitude = 0 and Longitude <> 0 (or vice-versa). OP hasn't said whether that's a valid possiblity :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
update  V
set latitude= (select top 1 latitude from VehicleData V2 where v2.timestamp < v.timestamp  and latitude!= 0 order by v2.timestamp desc),
    longitude= (select top 1 longitude from VehicleData V2 where v2.timestamp < v.timestamp and longitude !=0 order by v2.timestamp desc)
from VehicleData V
where V.latitude=0 and V.longitude=0
```